# How to calculate image matching percentage using opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, percentage, feature-extraction, orb

I want to compare a template image with 3 images to find the matching image using opencv ORB feature extractor and matching.

I don't know how to match the images keypoints with the template after obtaining kepoints to find matching percentage?

For example: I need to check 'image of an apple' with 'image of banana', image of orange and 'image of apple with different background'. 
The program should say that template image(image of apple) matches with 3rd image(image of apple with different background) with 70% match or something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you define the **similarity percentage**, what is the basic definition of *similarity* in this case?

Comment: can you provide the template image and the other 3 images?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to make apples to orange comparisions using image-processing. Perhaps you want to categorize your object in terms of its different properties-- e.g., color range, shape, etc. Compile a set of instructions for comparing each sample to the template, but for a defined criteria, as suggested by ZdaR.